# Where in an Android project is it recommended to place startup code?

Tags: android

I'd like to set some system properties, like in this question: [what is the purpose of Java level DNS caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488587/what-is-the-purpose-of-java-level-dns-caching)

Where would you put the `System.setProperty` code?

Comment: In a place that makes sense for you and happens before you do the networking.

Comment: @zapl, Isn't there some standard location for initializations?

Comment: There is no single entry `main` method in Android (at least no one that you can reach). So it comes down to how your class desing looks like. You could use a custom [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) since that is a singleton for your app and it should be created first.